# Freeradius : Specifying Number of DB Connection Handles to be made

Tags: oracle10g, radius, freeradius

I have recently deployed `FreeRadius 3.0.12` and I'm having an issue with the number of connections strings it makes with oracle DB. I have made the necessary amendments in the `oraclesql.conf` file and `radiusd.conf` file.

Please see contents of `oraclesql.conf.`

```
    sql {

        server = "<DB IP>"
        login = "<LOGIN>"
        password = "<Password>"

        # Database table configuration

        radius_db = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <DB IP>)(PORT = <PORT NO.>)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = SID)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))"



        # If you want both stop and start records logged to the
        # same SQL table, leave this as is.  If you want them in
        # different tables, put the start table in acct_table1
        # and stop table in acct_table2
        acct_table1 = "radacct"
        acct_table2 = "radacct"

        authcheck_table = "radcheck"
        authreply_table = "radreply"

        groupcheck_table = "radgroupcheck"
        groupreply_table = "radgroupreply"

        usergroup_table = "usergroup"

        # Remove stale session if checkrad does not see a double login
        delete_stale_sessions = no

        # Print all SQL statements when in debug mode (-x)
        sqltrace = yes
        sqltracefile = ${logdir}/sqltrace.sql

        # number of sql connections to make to server
        num_sql_socks = 100

        # number of seconds to dely retrying on a failed database
        # connection (per_socket)
        connect_failure_retry_delay = 60
```

As you can see `num_sql_socks = 100` has been set.

Please see output of `Radius -X`

```
   rlm_sql (sql): Driver rlm_sql_oracle (module rlm_sql_oracle) loaded and linked
Creating attribute SQL-Group
  instantiate {
  }
  # Instantiating module "cache_eap" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/cache_eap
rlm_cache (cache_eap): Driver rlm_cache_rbtree (module rlm_cache_rbtree) loaded and linked
  # Instantiating module "pap" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/pap
  # Instantiating module "auth_log" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
rlm_detail (auth_log): 'User-Password' suppressed, will not appear in detail output
  # Instantiating module "reply_log" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
  # Instantiating module "pre_proxy_log" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
  # Instantiating module "post_proxy_log" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail.log
  # Instantiating module "eap" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/eap
   # Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_md5
   # Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_leap
   # Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_gtc
   gtc {
    challenge = "Password: "
    auth_type = "PAP"
   }
   # Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_tls
   tls {
    tls = "tls-common"
   }
   tls-config tls-common {
    verify_depth = 0
    ca_path = "/etc/raddb/certs"
    pem_file_type = yes
    private_key_file = "/etc/raddb/certs/server.pem"
    certificate_file = "/etc/raddb/certs/server.pem"
    ca_file = "/etc/raddb/certs/ca.pem"
    private_key_password = <<< secret >>>
    dh_file = "/etc/raddb/certs/dh"
    fragment_size = 1024
    include_length = yes
    auto_chain = yes
    check_crl = no
    check_all_crl = no
    cipher_list = "DEFAULT"
    ecdh_curve = "prime256v1"
    cache {
        enable = yes
        lifetime = 24
        max_entries = 255
    }
    verify {
        skip_if_ocsp_ok = no
    }
    ocsp {
        enable = no
        override_cert_url = yes
        url = "http://127.0.0.1/ocsp/"
        use_nonce = yes
        timeout = 0
        softfail = no
    }
   }
   # Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_ttls
   ttls {
    tls = "tls-common"
    default_eap_type = "md5"
    copy_request_to_tunnel = no
    use_tunneled_reply = no
    virtual_server = "inner-tunnel"
    include_length = yes
    require_client_cert = no
   }
tls: Using cached TLS configuration from previous invocation
   # Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_peap
   peap {
    tls = "tls-common"
    default_eap_type = "mschapv2"
    copy_request_to_tunnel = no
    use_tunneled_reply = no
    proxy_tunneled_request_as_eap = yes
    virtual_server = "inner-tunnel"
    soh = no
    require_client_cert = no
   }
tls: Using cached TLS configuration from previous invocation
   # Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_mschapv2
   mschapv2 {
    with_ntdomain_hack = no
    send_error = no
   }
  # Instantiating module "detail" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/detail
  # Instantiating module "reject" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "fail" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "ok" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "handled" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "invalid" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "userlock" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "notfound" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "noop" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "updated" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
  # Instantiating module "linelog" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/linelog
  # Instantiating module "log_accounting" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/linelog
  # Instantiating module "etc_passwd" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/passwd
rlm_passwd: nfields: 3 keyfield 0(User-Name) listable: no
  # Instantiating module "mschap" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/mschap
rlm_mschap (mschap): using internal authentication
  # Instantiating module "preprocess" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/preprocess
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/preprocess/huntgroups
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/preprocess/hints
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.post-proxy" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/post-proxy
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.pre-proxy" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/pre-proxy
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.access_reject" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/access_reject
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.access_challenge" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/access_challenge
  # Instantiating module "attr_filter.accounting_response" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/attr_filter
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/attr_filter/accounting_response
  # Instantiating module "logintime" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/logintime
  # Instantiating module "IPASS" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/realm
  # Instantiating module "suffix" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/realm
  # Instantiating module "realmpercent" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/realm
  # Instantiating module "ntdomain" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/realm
  # Instantiating module "files" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/files
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/files/authorize
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/files/accounting
reading pairlist file /etc/raddb/mods-config/files/pre-proxy
  # Instantiating module "expiration" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/expiration
  # Instantiating module "sql" from file /etc/raddb/oraclesql.conf
rlm_sql (sql): Attempting to connect to database "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <DP IP>)(PORT = <PORT NO.>)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = SID)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))"
rlm_sql (sql): Initialising connection pool
   pool {
    start = 5
    min = 5
    max = 10
    spare = 3
    uses = 0
    lifetime = 0
    cleanup_interval = 30
    idle_timeout = 60
    retry_delay = 1
    spread = no
   }
rlm_sql (sql): Opening additional connection (0), 1 of 10 pending slots used
rlm_sql (sql): Opening additional connection (1), 1 of 9 pending slots used
rlm_sql (sql): Opening additional connection (2), 1 of 8 pending slots used
rlm_sql (sql): Opening additional connection (3), 1 of 7 pending slots used
rlm_sql (sql): Opening additional connection (4), 1 of 6 pending slots used
 } # modules
radiusd: #### Loading Virtual Servers ####
server { # from file /etc/raddb/radiusd.conf
} # server
server inner-tunnel { # from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/inner-tunnel
 # Loading authenticate {...}
 # Loading authorize {...}
Ignoring "ldap" (see raddb/mods-available/README.rst)
 # Loading session {...}
 # Loading post-proxy {...}
 # Loading post-auth {...}
} # server inner-tunnel
server default { # from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
 # Loading authenticate {...}
 # Loading authorize {...}
 # Loading preacct {...}
 # Loading accounting {...}
 # Loading post-proxy {...}
 # Loading post-auth {...}
} # server default
radiusd: #### Opening IP addresses and Ports ####
listen {
    type = "auth"
    ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
    port = 18120
}
listen {
    type = "auth"
    ipaddr = *
    port = 0
   limit {
    max_connections = 16
    lifetime = 0
    idle_timeout = 30
   }
}
listen {
    type = "acct"
    ipaddr = *
    port = 0
   limit {
    max_connections = 16
    lifetime = 0
    idle_timeout = 30
   }
}
listen {
    type = "auth"
    ipv6addr = ::
    port = 0
   limit {
    max_connections = 16
    lifetime = 0
    idle_timeout = 30
   }
}
listen {
    type = "acct"
    ipv6addr = ::
    port = 0
   limit {
    max_connections = 16
    lifetime = 0
    idle_timeout = 30
   }
}
Listening on auth address 127.0.0.1 port 18120 bound to server inner-tunnel
Listening on auth address * port 1812 bound to server default
Listening on acct address * port 1813 bound to server default
Listening on auth address :: port 1812 bound to server default
Listening on acct address :: port 1813 bound to server default
Listening on proxy address * port 33624
Listening on proxy address :: port 18999
Ready to process requests
```

Please see Thread Pool section of `radiusd.conf`

```
thread pool {
        #  Number of servers to start initially --- should be a reasonable
        #  ballpark figure.
        start_servers = 25

        #  Limit on the total number of servers running.
        #
        #  If this limit is ever reached, clients will be LOCKED OUT, so it
        #  should NOT BE SET TOO LOW.  It is intended mainly as a brake to
        #  keep a runaway server from taking the system with it as it spirals
        #  down...
        #
        #  You may find that the server is regularly reaching the
        #  'max_servers' number of threads, and that increasing
        #  'max_servers' doesn't seem to make much difference.
        #
        #  If this is the case, then the problem is MOST LIKELY that
        #  your back-end databases are taking too long to respond, and
        #  are preventing the server from responding in a timely manner.
        #
        #  The solution is NOT do keep increasing the 'max_servers'
        #  value, but instead to fix the underlying cause of the
        #  problem: slow database, or 'hostname_lookups=yes'.
        #
        #  For more information, see 'max_request_time', above.
        #
        max_servers = 100

        #  Server-pool size regulation.  Rather than making you guess
        #  how many servers you need, FreeRADIUS dynamically adapts to
        #  the load it sees, that is, it tries to maintain enough
        #  servers to handle the current load, plus a few spare
        #  servers to handle transient load spikes.
        #
        #  It does this by periodically checking how many servers are
        #  waiting for a request.  If there are fewer than
        #  min_spare_servers, it creates a new spare.  If there are
        #  more than max_spare_servers, some of the spares die off.
        #  The default values are probably OK for most sites.
        #
        min_spare_servers = 10
        max_spare_servers = 20

        #  When the server receives a packet, it places it onto an
        #  internal queue, where the worker threads (configured above)
        #  pick it up for processing.  The maximum size of that queue
        #  is given here.
        #
        #  When the queue is full, any new packets will be silently
        #  discarded.
        #
        #  The most common cause of the queue being full is that the
        #  server is dependent on a slow database, and it has received
        #  a large "spike" of traffic.  When that happens, there is
        #  very little you can do other than make sure the server
        #  receives less traffic, or make sure that the database can
        #  handle the load.
        #
#       max_queue_size = 65536

        #  There may be memory leaks or resource allocation problems with
        #  the server.  If so, set this value to 300 or so, so that the
        #  resources will be cleaned up periodically.
        #
        #  This should only be necessary if there are serious bugs in the
        #  server which have not yet been fixed.
        #
        #  '0' is a special value meaning 'infinity', or 'the servers never
        #  exit'
        max_requests_per_server = 0

        #  Automatically limit the number of accounting requests.
        #  This configuration item tracks how many requests per second
        #  the server can handle.  It does this by tracking the
        #  packets/s received by the server for processing, and
        #  comparing that to the packets/s handled by the child
        #  threads.
        #

        #  If the received PPS is larger than the processed PPS, *and*
        #  the queue is more than half full, then new accounting
```

A Sample of connection strings that should be made is as follows (from `Radius -X` of a separate freeradius v2.x ):

```
rlm_sql (sql): Driver rlm_sql_oracle (module rlm_sql_oracle) loaded and linked
rlm_sql (sql): Attempting to connect to radius@<DB IP>:/(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <DB IP>)(PORT = <DB PORT>)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = <SID>)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))
rlm_sql (sql): starting 0
rlm_sql (sql): Attempting to connect rlm_sql_oracle #0
rlm_sql (sql): Connected new DB handle, #0
rlm_sql (sql): starting 1
rlm_sql (sql): Attempting to connect rlm_sql_oracle #1
rlm_sql (sql): Connected new DB handle, #1
rlm_sql (sql): starting 2
rlm_sql (sql): Attempting to connect rlm_sql_oracle #2
rlm_sql (sql): Connected new DB handle, #2
rlm_sql (sql): starting 3
rlm_sql (sql): Attempting to connect rlm_sql_oracle #3
rlm_sql (sql): Connected new DB handle, #3
rlm_sql (sql): starting 4
rlm_sql (sql): Attempting to connect rlm_sql_oracle #4
rlm_sql (sql): Connected new DB handle, #4
rlm_sql (sql): starting 5
rlm_sql (sql): Attempting to connect rlm_sql_oracle #5
rlm_sql (sql): Connected new DB handle, #5
rlm_sql (sql): starting 6
rlm_sql (sql): Attempting to connect rlm_sql_oracle #6
rlm_sql (sql): Connected new DB handle, #6
rlm_sql (sql): starting 7
rlm_sql (sql): Attempting to connect rlm_sql_oracle #7
rlm_sql (sql): Connected new DB handle, #7
rlm_sql (sql): starting 8
rlm_sql (sql): Attempting to connect rlm_sql_oracle #8
rlm_sql (sql): Connected new DB handle, #8
rlm_sql (sql): starting 9
rlm_sql (sql): Attempting to connect rlm_sql_oracle #9
rlm_sql (sql): Connected new DB handle, #9
rlm_sql (sql): starting 10
rlm_sql (sql): Attempting to connect rlm_sql_oracle #10
rlm_sql (sql): Connected new DB handle, #10
rlm_sql (sql): starting 11

and so on to a 99 ...
```

Is there some place else I need to make an edit in order to form the required connection. Any guidance on the matter would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

So , I figured it out, Adding the below to the `sql.conf` file fixed it.

```
pool {
        start = 25
        min = 25
        max = 25
        spare = 0
        uses = 0 
        lifetime = 0
        cleanup_interval = 0
        #cleanup_interval = 30
        idle_timeout = 0
        #idle_timeout = 60
        retry_delay = 1
        spread = no
   }
```

where,

```
num_sql_socks               -> pool { max }
connect_failure_retry_delay -> pool { retry_delay }
lifetime                    -> pool { lifetime }
max_queries                 -> pool { uses }
```

A bit of extra information, the structure for SQL queries has changed from Fixed to Dynamic according to [this](http://networkradius.com/doc/current/upgrading/changed-modules.html).
The queries can be found in :

```
<radiusdir>/modsconfig/sql/main/<db>/queries.conf
```

The queries are the same though. Hopefully this helps when upgrading to `freeradius 3.x`.